# Is there a way to compute distance if we know the foreshortening ratio?

Tags: trigonometry

A tree on mountain top when observed by an observer standing right next to it is 35 feet tall. Another observer standing on the foothills observes the same tree to be 7 millimeters, or about 0.023 feet.

Is there a way to compute the distance between the two observers with this information?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you know how far you are from the $7$mm image, then yes.

If for example you hold your ruler at arms length and measure the tree's image as $7$mm then the ratio of the unknown distance to the length of your arm is the ratio of $7$mm to $35$ feet.